# How I can read dataframe in R Markdown using SQL?

Tags: sql, r, markdown, r-markdown

I can read data from database using this code:

```
{sql connection=con} SELECT year, sex, age from INFROMATION
```

but how I can take that to data.frame?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html#sql):

> If you want to assign the results of the SQL query to an R data frame, you can do this using the `output.var` option.

For example:

```
{sql, connection=con, output.var="info_query"}
SELECT year, sex, age from INFROMATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put that directly in data = data.frame({sql connection=con} SELECT year, sex, age from INFROMATION) ?